# why does appending a foreignObject into an SVG break jquery ui's resize?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, coffeescript

I've got a piechart that's built with D3, the markup looks like:

```
<div class="display">
  <svg height="300">
    <g transform="translate(140,125)">
      <g class="slice">
        <path fill="#3182bd" d="M-103.92304845413268,-59.99999999999993A120,120 0 0,1 -1.2862432473281782e-13,-120L0,0Z"></path>
        <text transform="translate(-30.000000000000075,-51.96152422706628)" text-anchor="middle">A</text>
      </g>
      <g class="slice">
        <path fill="#6baed6" d="M7.347638122934264e-15,120A120,120 0 0,1 -103.92304845413268,-59.99999999999993L0,0Z"></path>
        <text transform="translate(-51.961524227066306,30.00000000000002)" text-anchor="middle">B</text>
      </g>
      <g class="slice">
        <path fill="#9ecae1" d="M7.347638122934264e-15,-120A120,120 0 1,1 7.347638122934264e-15,120L0,0Z"></path>
        <text transform="translate(60,0)" text-anchor="middle">C</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <div class="pieChartTooltip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; visibility: visible; top: 32px; left: 192px;">C: 3.00</div>
</div>
```

Ok nifty. Then I wanted to be able to resize the container that it's in (angular directive):

```
.directive("resizable", [ "debounce", (debounce) ->
  restrict: "A"
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    broadcastResize = (event, ui) ->
      scope.$root.$broadcast "resize", ui.element.parents(".widget"), ui.size

    debounceResize = debounce(broadcastResize, 800, false)
    element.resizable
      grid: 10
      helper: "ui-resizable-helper"
      stop: (event, ui) ->
        debounceResize event, ui
])
```

All fine. Next I wanted to add an overlay for the pie chart that said "sample data" or "refreshed at 3:45" or other things like that. So I added this code to the object that builds the pie chart (coffee):

```
drawOverlay: (msg) => 
  @logger.debug 'drawing overlay' 
  vis = d3.select(@selector + " svg ")
  @logger.warn "no svg vis found" unless vis?
  x = (@model.width / 2 ) - 75
  y = (@model.height / 2 ) - 50

  @jq(@selector + " svg foreignObject").remove()

  text = vis.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", "widgetOverlay")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .html('<div>' + msg + '</div>')
```

Here's the problem: adding that overlay causes jquery ui's resize helper to get "stuck" on screen -- but only the first time it's drawn. Subsequent resizes work fine. I suspect it's because of the second body tag that gets inserted in the svg. As far as I know it is required -- taking it out caused the overlay to not be appended. If I put a return at the top of `drawOverlay` the resize directive works just fine. So it seems clear where the problem lies, I'm wondering if anyone can explain why this is happening -- and maybe offer a fix.

Answer (score 0):

If adding a `body` tag confuses `jquery.ui`, then why not skip the `body` tag and append the `div` directly?

```
var msg = 'Hello World';
var x = 150, y = 150;
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 300)
    .attr('height', 300)
  .append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", "widgetOverlay")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 50)
  .append('xhtml:div')
    .text(msg);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FAJdW/)

Comment: I tried that a while back and the overlay didn't show up. Your sample doesn't have any svg elements under the overlay, so that's probably why you are seeing it.